# Using shiny render functions in a magrittr pipeline such as renderTable renderPlot inside html_notebook with shiny runtime

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

Is it possible to use the `shiny::render*` family of functions at the end of a pipeline `%>%`? Specifically, when using an `html_notebook` with a `runtime: shiny`.

Instead of: `renderTable({mtcars[1:5, ]})` is it possible to do something like: `mtcars[1:5, ] %>% renderTable()`?

**Example**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)

renderTable({
  mtcars[1:5, ]
})    
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
renderTable({
  mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == 4) %>%
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(avg_gear = mean(gear),
              sd_carb = sd(carb))
})

# NOTE: This does not work!
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(avg_gear = mean(gear),
            sd_carb = sd(carb)) %>%
  renderTable()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(avg_gear = mean(gear),
            sd_carb = sd(carb)) %>%
  renderTable(quoted = TRUE) # quoted defaults to FALSE
```